# Tracing Connected Pixels

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencv

I want to trace all the connected pixels of an image. I used the canny algorithm for edge detection and now need to get each unique shape.

[image]
here is my code  for the following

```
x_axis = marker_i;   // x & y co-ordinates of the first detected pixels
y_axis = marker_j;

do
{

for (int i=0;i<8;i++){

if(i==0){x_axis = x_axis-1;  y_axis = y_axis-1;}  // each iteration checks one 
if(i==1){x_axis = x_axis;    y_axis = y_axis+1;}  // of the 8 adjacent pixels 
if(i==2){x_axis = x_axis;    y_axis = y_axis+1;}  // for a match 
if(i==3){x_axis = x_axis+1;  y_axis = y_axis-2;}
if(i==4){x_axis = x_axis;    y_axis = y_axis+2;}
if(i==5){x_axis = x_axis+1;  y_axis = y_axis-2;}
if(i==6){x_axis = x_axis;    y_axis = y_axis+1;}
if(i==7){x_axis = x_axis;    y_axis = y_axis+1;}

if(x_axis >= 1024 || y_axis >= 1280){ x_axis = 0; y_axis = 0;}

if(ch_rd == red [x_axis][y_axis] && ch_gr == green[x_axis][y_axis] 
&& ch_bl == blue[x_axis][y_axis] && pixel_comp[x_axis][y_axis]==0){ 

map++;
pixel_comp[x_axis][y_axis] = 2;                  // marks that pixel as read
pixal[num][0]    = x_axis;
pixal[num][1]    = y_axis;

if (map == 1){ curs[0] = x_axis; curs[1] = y_axis;}
if (map >  1){ div[est] = num; est++;}   // if there is more than one detection
num++;                                   // adds remaining to an array div

}

}

if(map==0){ 
x_axis = pixal[div[prev]][0]; y_axis = pixal[div[prev]][1]; prev++; 
    // if nothing is detected goes to the last item from array div
}
else{ 
x_axis = curs[0]; y_axis = curs[1]; 
} 
if(map==0 && prev>=est){ dead_end = 1;}
map = 0;
}
while (dead_end==0);
```

I was using this on a previous version of my program and it would unfortuantely detect all shapes even if they were not connected instead of one by one, now i've been trying opencv and was wondering if there was a function or implementation which does this or even an non-opencv implementation or example that i could use ? What is a simple algorithm for this purpose ?

Comment: Google extracting connected components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is the Wikipedia article on [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) . This has animations of the filling algorithm.

[You didn't ask for corrections to your program.]

Comment: the algorithm works now, i had changed an initialization value that is not available in this code and it gave me errors, now it is fixed.

Comment: I suspect your algorithm is a flood-fill. If so you could vote this answer